# Detail view controller back button title does not update with master view controller title

Tags: swift, uisplitviewcontroller, ios11, swift4

I have an ios app that uses splitview controller. The title of masterviewcontroller contains number of unhandled records also. Like "Records (15)". From detailviewcontroller, the record can be marked as handled. The function to mark handled is declared in masterviewcontroller and when it is marked has handled, the title changes to include the unhandled number. For example to "Records (14)" in this case.

With iOS 10, this title change reflected well on back button of detailviewcontroller automatically which makes sense as title of back button is bound to title of previous viewcontroller. But the title of back button does not update on iOS11. I know a lot of changes are made for navigation bar in ios11. But how to update the back button title now?

This is my first question on SO. Please excuse if the question is not fully with guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is by design or a bug in iOS 11. One way to solve this issue is to manually manage the back button in your master view controller.

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Records (\(counter))", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

Note: you will need to create a new bar button item instance each time, simply updating the title will sadly not work.

Hope this helps

Comment: I've filed a radar for this issue to get a clarification (35119951)

Comment: Seems to be a bug, I'm seeing the same thing.  Rotating to landscape (on a non plus iPhone) and the title correctly updates, so it doesn't appear to be a case of it not accepting the updated value, just not refreshing to show it.